# How do I make GNOME panels transparent in classic mode?

Tags: 11.04, gnome-panel, gnome

I would like to have my gnome panels transparent like I had them in 10.10. I used this [guide](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/02/gnome-panel-transparency-fix-ubuntu/) (scroll down a bit) to make them transparent in 10.10, but it doesn't seem to work, at least with the Equinox themes. I am using 11.04 Classic and the Equinox Dawn theme. If there's anymore information needed for the problem, let me know and I'll provide it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just to make sure, were you using the Equinox Dawn theme in 10.10?

Comment: No, I was using an edited Ambiance theme. I hadn't tried anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a different way of doing this but it is with compiz is you install the  "compiz config settings manager" and go to "opacity,brightness and saturation" on the opacity tab down at the bottom hit the new button,and add

name=gnome-panel

your panel will disappear just slide the bar over to adjust the opacity. be careful with compiz and 11.04 it seems to break easily.

Comment: For whatever reason, doing that completely broke Compiz, and I guess I'll reinstall later today. In any case, however, I'd much rather use gnome-panel settings for this. Another advantage of using the gnome-panel is that you can also put your own colors or images for the panel.

Comment: well that sucks, i have done the same hack on 10.10 but i use theme in my home folder,in the    .theme     folder. if its an Ambiance theme you are trying to edit you can download a few from Gnome look. i cant put a link right now i guess the site is down. the last time i had problems with 11.04 and compiz i had to log into ubuntu classic with out FX and open the terminal and add each line one at a time.....

gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1 

gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/compizconfig-1

Comment: sorry if its hard to see the lines (1) gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1 and then (2) gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/compizconfig-1